# Determine a function $f$ from the given conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

We are given a set $P$ of continuous functions $f : \bar{\mathbb{D}} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which satisfy the following properties: ($\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ |z| <1 \}$, and $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ is the closure of $\mathbb{D}$).

1. When restricted to the open unit disc, $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic.
2. $f(- \log 2) = 0$
3. $|f(z)| \leq |e^z| \ \ \forall z \ \text{ such that } |z| = 1$

Now say $M = \sup_{f \in P}\{|f(\log 2)|\}$.
I have to find **a)** the value of $M$, and **b)** Produce an explicit function $f \in S$ such that $|f(\log 2)| = M$.

How should I tackle this problem? I have a feeling that condition 3. along with 1. gives a boundedness of sorts, but I am not sure about that and how to use the other conditions to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Consider $g(z)=f(z)e^{-z}$ Then $g$ maps the disc to itself, vanishes at $-\log 2$ and you need to find its maximum at $\log 2$ as that is obviously the maximum of $f$ too; this is standard Schwarz pick stuff so the solution is the automorphism of the disc that has the given zero up to multiplicative constant of modulus $1$

Comment: @Conrad I am not at all familiar with "Scharz pick". Could you maybe elaborate the procedure by using a different method?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem it is just an application of Schwarz lemma to $g=\phi \circ f$ where $\phi$ is a disc automorphism that sends $-\log 2 \to 0$ so $g$ satisfies Schwarz